# Interrupt a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am writing a program to move a toy car using voice commands I am using threads to send data concurrently the problem is that I am not able to interrupt my thread when i use command exit please any help.

```
if(response.equals("stop"))
   {
         motorLeft = 0;
         motorRight =0;
         (new Thread(new Runnable()
           {@Override
               public  void run()
               {
                   while (!Thread.interrupted())
                       try
                       {
                           Thread.sleep(1000);
                           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() // start actions in UI thread
                           {

                               @Override
                               public void run()
                               {
                                  // displayData(); // this action have to be in UI thread
                                 if(BT_is_connect) bl.sendData(String.valueOf( commandLeft+motorLeft+"\r"+commandRight+motorRight+"\r"));

                               }
                           });
                       }
                       catch (InterruptedException e)
                       {
                           // ooops
                       }
               }
           })).start(); // the while thread will start in BG thread
      }
      else

      {
         if(response.equals("exit"))   
            Thread.interrupted();


         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a variable for example

```
volatile  boolean interrupted = false;
```

Then use that variable to stop the

```
 while (!interrupted)
 {
         try
         {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() // start actions in UI thread
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    // displayData(); // this action have to be in UI thread
                    if(BT_is_connect) bl.sendData(String.valueOf(commandLeft+motorLeft+"\r"+commandRight+motorRight+"\r"));

                }
            });
        }
         catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
             // ooops
        }       
 }
```

So when you want to interrupt the thread you can just change the **interrupted** variable to true

```
interrupted = true;
```

Comment: **volatile** boolean interrupted